# Docker me bloquea la terminal

Tags: docker, terminal

Tengo abierto docker desktop en MacOS. Cualquier comando que intento de docker me bloquea la terminal. Si intento `docker images prune`, o `docker ps`, o cualquier comando de docker, la terminal se me queda bloqueada.
He probado lo típico, reiniciar el ordenador y desinstalar y reinstalar docker desktop, pero el problema persiste.